# Do you need to use a framework to Ajaxify your java web app?

Tags: ajax, hibernate, jsf, jakarta-ee

I am currently studying Java EE with Hibernate for a project. In The Web App I am creating I am planning to Ajaxify page contents, and Site wide audio player(Which I think would be implemented using AJAX).

I am using a JSP based MVC, no frameworks, Just Java EE and Hibernate. And I've heard that I need to use a Framework like JSF to be able to AJaxify may web-app. How true is this? Do I really need to learn JSF or other frameworks to be able to Ajaxify my web app? As much as possible I do not want to learn a new framework for now since it is a big learning curve. but if there's no other way to Ajaxify my web app, I'll study a framework.

Comment: The new major iteration of JSF in JEE doesn't require any addons to achieve ajax functionality. [This blog](http://mkblog.exadel.com/2010/04/learning-jsf-2-ajax-in-jsf-using-fajax-tag/) by one of the maintainers of the Richfaces JSF library is a good place to get started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't **have** to adopt any framework to use partial page updates and similar, you can construct and send requests "manually" with JavaScript, but this is **much** more tedious then using a framework like JSF, maybe coupled with a component library like primefaces.

EDIT: you can find an abundance of examples of ajax capabilities in the [primefaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/home.jsf). Primefaces uses JQuery internally.

EDIT2: I have found some resources on how to dispatch ajax requests with JQuery from a JSP page (I assumed that using JSP was almost equal to not using a framework ;)): [here](http://soundcrisis.wordpress.com/2009/04/19/jsp-javaserver-pages-and-jquery-ajax/) and [here](http://www.programming-free.com/2012/08/ajax-with-jsp-and-servlet-using-jquery.html). I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: can you give any links or resources regarding this? A java web app that is ajaxified?  And Using Jquery is suggested.

Comment: @KyelJmD have added a link to a suite of ajaxified components.

Comment: The question is more, which framework is *not* using jQuery. RichFaces is also a good extension framework to JSF.

Comment: @kostja ooops sorry, what I meant was a Java Web that doesn't use a framework, rather just a standard java EE app that is ajaxified. Sorry for the misinformation.

Comment: @KyelJmD I'm not aware of a single publicly available site created with java that does not use a framework for ajax capabilities. This might also be a hint regarding the "need to use a framework" - it's a productivity driven decision.

Comment: I see, But are there sites that uses JQuery Ajax that is a java based web app? maybe even that something should exist?

Comment: @KyelJmD - have added some info WRT ajax with jquery & java

Answer (score 0):

To add on @Kostja's answer - 
I totally agree with him, with Ajax you just need to have a servlet to handle the HTTP requests, and proper JavaScript code. 
Besides JSF,I would also consider to look at Apache Wicket - you can read [here](http://java.dzone.com/news/interview-how-wicket-does-ajax) how Wicket handles Ajax. 
The reason I'm suggesting Wicket is that it's more comfortable to some developers to work with somewhat more "component oriented" (swing-like) framework.